# Bluebird.js: How to add wait for each iteration of Promise.map?

Tags: node.js, bluebird

I am processing an array using Promise.map. For each element I am performing an async operation which returns a promise. However, I want to introduce some delay between each call because the downstream has a limit on the number of requests. Here is what I want to do

```
return Promise.map(array, function (elem){
    // perform an async call using elem
    // wait for 500 ms
})
```

How can I achieve the same ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> because the downstream has a limit on the number of requests

The solution to this type of problem is to limit the number of simultaneous requests that you make.  Using a delay would just be a guess as to how to control that, but not precise at all.  Instead, you should literally limit the number of requests you have in flight at the same time.

> How can I achieve the same ?

Fortunately for you, Bluebird has a concurrency option exactly for controlling how many requests are in-flight at the same time with the `Promise.map()` method by setting the `concurrency` option.  Let's say you found that it was safe to have two requests in flight at the same time.  Then, you could do this:

```
return Promise.map(array, function (elem){
    // perform an async call, return a promise from that async call
}, {concurrency: 2});
```

This will manage the iteration through the array so that no more than 2 async operations are in flight at the same time.  You can obviously set `concurrency` to whatever value you find appropriate.

The `Promise.mapSeries()` method is a special case of `Promise.map()` with `concurrency` already set to 1.  So, if you truly wanted the calls to be sequential (with only one in-flight at any given time), then you could just use the `Promise.mapSeries()` method instead.

Answer (score 4):

Delay won't help as all items of the array are still going to be processed (or start getting processed) at the same time.

You need to set the [`concurrency` option](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html#map-option-concurrency)

```
return Promise.map(array, function (elem){
    // perform an async call using elem
    // wait for 500 ms
}, {concurrency: 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you are adding any function like add inside map function

```
function add(value) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
       // some operations
        resolve(value + 1);
    }).then(function (newValue) {
        return // result;
    });
}
```

You can delay it by add `.dealy()`

e.g

```
return Promise.map(array, function (elem){
    // perform an async call using elem
    // wait for 500 ms
    return add(1).delay(500); 
})
```

Hope this information help you.

Comment: This doesn't actually add a delay between calls.  It adds a delay until all the calls report that they are done, but doesn't actually change when the requests are sent.  By default, `Promise.map()` runs everything in parallel so your `.delay()` isn't changing when the requests are sent at all.  It's only changing when they report that they are done.